# Changing the in text citation for specific entries

Tags: latex, biblatex

I have been looking for an answer to my problem for quite a while now and was not able to find one that really meets my requirements.

I am using `biblatex` with citestyle `alphabetic`. For most cases this is absolutely fine. But now I would like to cite a study and would like a specific set of letters to appear in the text.

The biblatex source looks as follows:

```
@Report{Kost2018,
  author        = {Kost, Christoph and Shammugam, Shivenes},
  title         = {{Levelized Cost of Electricity Renewable Energy Technologies}},
  institution   = {Fraunhofer ISE},
  year          = {2018},
}
```

Now, with `\autocite{Kost2018}`, as expected, the citation comes out as `[Kos+18]`.

What I would like instead is something like `[ISE18]` because the reader will more likely know this institute rather than the author. Also, if I cite several studies of that insistute, it is more clear to the reader.

I would be really greatfull if someone could help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`biblatex`](//ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) key `shorthand`:

```
@Report{Kost2018,
  author        = {Kost, Christoph and Shammugam, Shivenes},
  shorthand     = {ISE18},
  title         = {{Levelized Cost of Electricity Renewable Energy Technologies}},
  institution   = {Fraunhofer ISE},
  year          = {2018}
}
```

Description from the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf):

> `label`
>   A designation to be used by the citation style as a substitute for the regular label if
>   any data required to generate the regular label is missing. For example, when an
>   author-year citation style is generating a citation for an entry which is missing the
>   author or the year, it may fall back to label. See § [2.3.2](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for details. Note that, in contrast to `shorthand`, `label` is only used as a fallback. See also `shorthand`.
>
> `shorthand`
>   A special designation to be used by the citation style instead of the usual label. If
>   defined, it overrides the default label. See also `label`.

Reference: [How to specify bibliography alpha key without modifying the `.bst` file or using BibLaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/377969/5764)